# How can I trigger the boot process of a bootable CD after normal boot?

Tags: windows, linux, dos, boot, bootloader

I have been fooling around with different versions of Multiple boot softwares, trying to create a USB pin with my favorite PC tools and a folder with ISO's for which to boot after a normal boot into DOS (or something).

But a lot of ISO's don't work correctly, or at all (ie. Windows boot CD's etc.), so I got a new idea:

Would it be possible to create a bootable MS-DOS USB pin, and then after having booted, trigger the normal booting sequences of a CD-rom from the DOS prompt?

Like this:

- Turn on PC.
- Hit key to get boot sequence menu (in my case F12).
- Select "Boot from USB".
- Let the USB boot into DOS (... or whatever else could be used for this purpose?).
- From DOS prompt start "*some program/script*" to trigger a bootable CD in the normal optical drive, as if it had been triggered directly from the BIOS boot sequence menu.

(if this was possible, I would then proceed to add a menu with the option to start virtual CD-drive software and mount ISO files to my USB pin)

Thanks for any advice and/or ideas and thoughts!

Comment: You can take a look at how Grub (the bootloader) does this. It basically loads and executes the boot sector, I believe

Comment: I found this on a sister site: http://superuser.com/questions/154133/grub-boot-from-iso

Might get you closer to what you're doing...

Comment: I've tried Grub in various different ways, but no luck. Maybe it's my ISO's (ie. one of them is the McAfee SafeBoot bootcd for working with endpoint encryption - I tried adding it to my USB with Xboot and YUMI, using Grub4dos ISO image emulation, MemDisk, etc. - no success so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, you can use [Int13h/AH=4Ch](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0720.htm) to start a CD-ROM boot from code running under the BIOS.  However, I seem to remember reading that most BIOS implementations don't actually implement this part of the [El Torito](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/specscdrom.pdf) standard.  (That was a long time ago, so perhaps you won't have this problem on a modern BIOS, although I wouldn't count on it.)

It is important to note that (in my experience) this is unlikely to work once you've booted an operating system.  DOS doesn't change the CPU mode (provided you don't install any extended memory drivers) but it does change the system context in other ways - for example, IIRC, it hooks several of the BIOS interrupts.  As a result once DOS is running you can't overwrite it (in order to boot another OS from a CD) without things falling over.

So, in order to make this work (a) you have to run your code in the bare BIOS, with no operating system present; and (b) you need a BIOS that implements the boot function properly.  The first part is just a matter of getting the hang of bare assembly and the [BIOS functions](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/cat-003.htm), but the second part is pretty much out of your control.

Comment: Thank you for this great explanation! That gives much more insight. I'm currently trying with EasyBCD and getting the same error as with Grub: The ISO is mounted and booting successfully, but then at the WinXP logo I suddenly get Blue screen of error 0x0000007B - I suppose this is triggered by the Int13h being handled incorrectly, so no cookie for me ;-(

Comment: Once you move away from booting the real CD drive and try to boot an ISO file you've got a whole different kettle of fish.  As soon as Windows (or other OS) stops using the BIOS I/O functions and tries to use its own device drivers, the virtualized CD drive disappears and everything collapses.  It might work with Windows PE version 3, though, because the first thing it does is to read the OS image into a RAMdisk, and I *think* it's still using the BIOS I/O at that point.